# Import a custom audience in Firebase Analytics

Tags: firebase-analytics

I am interested in creating an audience within Firebase Analytics using external information. In other words, given a set of IDs in a spreadsheet, I would like to import it as an audience.

This functionality is available for Google Analytics via data import (https://developers.google.com/analytics/solutions/data-import-user). I am wondering whether there is an equivalent for Firebase Analytics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is currently no way to import external audiences into Google Analytics for Firebase. I recommend that you [file a feature request](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/) for it, as it sounds really useful.

The best I can think right now of is setting a property on each user (in the app), which you then use to declare an audience in Analytics.